# redirect to url when user type mysitename.com in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have designed my website in asp.net and hosted it on web server. 
I want to redirect user to my site if user will type mydimainName.com on http://www.mydimainName.com.
If some one has solution then please let me know.

Thanks,

Munish

Comment: is it http://www.mydomainname.com/?

Comment: You should be able to set that up with your host, if both of the domain names are registered to you.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to redirect the user as soon as possible, so placing this in Application_BeginRequest of your Global.asax makes the most sense. You also likely want to do this as a 301 redirect for SEO purposes. Something like so is typically what I would do (not 100% tested)

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string sHost = Request.Url.Host.ToLower();

     if( sHost == "mydimainame.com" )
     {
          Response.StatusCode = 301;
          Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
          Response.AddHeader( "Location", "http://www.mydimainName.com");
          Response.End();
     }
}
```

Comment: this will route them all to the homepage

Comment: Yes, and the OP didn't ask for anything more.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in your masterpage or Global.asax:

```
            string req = Request.Url.ToString();
            string a = req.Substring(0, 10).ToLower();

            if (a != "http://www")
            {
```

// this is for localhost and my staging at discountasp,

```
                if (a != "http://loc" && !req.Contains("discountasp"))
                {
                    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                    Response.AddHeader("Location", "http://www." + req.Substring(7, req.Length - 7));
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
```